# KeyboardAvoidingView not work on android when I reopen activity

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a Android app with React-native and  I'm getting an error with `KeyboardAvoidingView`.

I have 2 views on separate files in my app and these 2 views have textInput's. I set the `KeyboardAvoidingView` component to encapsulate these 2 views and it works perfectly, however, when I close this app and reopen, I'm going back to the top of the view. Has anyone ever seen this error?

```
My enviroment:
Environment:
OS: Windows 10
Node: 10.7.0
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 6.1.0
Watchman: Not Found
Xcode: N/A
Android Studio: Version 3.1.0.0 AI-173.4819257

Packages: (wanted => installed)
react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a example from my source code (I'm developing for Android):

```
import React from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native'
import {Item, Input, Label, Content} from 'native-base'


const FormRegister = props => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.main} enabled>
        <Content contentContainerStyle={styles.loginArea}>
            <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label style={styles.label}>Nome</Label>
                    <Input style={styles.input} />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label style={styles.label}>CPF</Label>
                    <Input style={styles.input} />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label style={styles.label}>Telefone</Label>
                    <Input style={styles.input} />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label style={styles.label}>Email</Label>
                    <Input style={styles.input} />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label style={styles.label}>Senha</Label>
                    <Input style={styles.input} secureTextEntry />
            </Item>
            <Text style={styles.txtNewsAndTerms}>Ao criar sua conta, você 
          concorda com os <Text style={styles.styleTextTerms} onPress={() => 
       false}>Termos de Serviço</Text>
            e <Text style={styles.styleTextTerms} onPress={() => 
          false}>Política de Privacidade</Text>.</Text>

             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin} onPress={() => 
           false}>
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Cadastrar</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Content>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
 )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
     flex: 1,
     padding: 20,
     backgroundColor: '#fff',
     justifyContent: 'center'
 },
  loginArea: {
     flex: 5,
     justifyContent: 'center'
 },
  label: {
     fontSize: 14,
     color: '#00C853',
     marginTop: 10
 },
  input: {
     borderBottomColor: '#000',
     marginTop: 10
 },
  btnLogin: {
     padding: 10,
     marginTop: 40,
     backgroundColor: '#00C853',
     height: 50,
     borderRadius: 4,
     justifyContent: 'center'
},
btnText: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 18,
},
txtNewsAndTerms: {
    marginTop: 20
},
styleTextTerms: {
    color: '#00C853'
},
btnCadastrar: {
    flex: 1
}
})

export default FormRegister
```

Comment: Please include some code and also, if applicable, the _exact_ error you're seeing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have edited the question and it includes a snippet of my code where I am encapsulating TextFields with keyboardAvoidingView. Thank you for now.